# How to test getContent() calls in Spring '17?

Tags: unit-test, httpcalloutmock, spring17, getcontent, apexmock

Now that the Apex Mocks API and its Stub API complement are available is it possible to properly test for a `getContent()` call? In the past I would just branch out if unit test was running and returned a random blob. But my unit test is specifically testing for callout limits, and it is imperative for it to properly mimic an actual callout.

Basically I am trying to write a unit test that ensures exceptions such as this one are not thrown: "System.CalloutException, "You have uncommitted work pending"

Comment: How does your testing pattern affect uncommitted work pending?

Comment: If my unit test causes the `getContent()` call to run in Batch context I get that error. Conversely if it runs in trigger context I get the "cannot callout from trigger" exception (don't remember the exact wording). I have conditions in my code to take alternate routes if the above cases are encountered, and I need to ensure that they are executed correctly. These alternate routes eventually make the call to `getContent()` but in ways that should comply with the execution context.